# I wasn't ready for it

Tags: idiomatic-language

> I asked her this question that I thought was pretty harmless, but it
> made her break down crying. **I wasn't ready for it**, so I didn't
> know what to say.

Hi. Would "I wasn't ready for it" be perfectly natural in a context like this to tell that I was surprised and unprepared as I didn't saw it coming?

Comment: I suggest you try googling that and see what you get.

Comment: Seems natural to me, but I would use "I wasn't ready for **that**" personally.

Comment: Use "ready for that".  It would be better to use "that" to refer the thing that happened in the previous sentence.  "It" is too vague/ambiguous here.

Comment: Can you edit to tell more about why you're concerned about it? That would give better answers.